# Does %matplotlib qt works in google colab?

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I was using matplotlib and found out that there is something as interactive plots in matplotlib via which we can rotate the graph via mouse cursor

**%matplotlib qt** is used to enable the interactive plots.Works fine in jupyter notebook but google colab shows error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyq4C.png)

Is there any chance it works in google colab also?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no chance. `%matplotlib qt`works only if you have notebook executed on same machine as you use it. Colab is executed on remote server. <strike>You may try `%matplotlib notebook` This create interactive plot inside notebook.</strike>